# How to unit test angular material md datepicker?

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, angular-material

How can I test how to manually open an angular material directive for unit testing?

```
          <div layout-gt-xs="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <md-input-container>
                        <label class="input-label">{{ 'policyform.DOB' | translate }}</label>
                        <md-datepicker ng-model="vm.data.dob" name="policyHolderDob"
                            ng-required="vm.config.dob.required"
                            md-min-date="vm.minDate"
                            md-max-date="vm.maxDate"
                            min-age="{{vm.config.dob.minage}}"
                            max-age="{{vm.config.dob.maxage}}">
                        </md-datepicker>
                        <uex-form-validation form="vm.policyForm" field="policyHolderDob" config="vm.config.dob"></uex-form-validation>
                    </md-input-container>
               </div>
          </div>
```

Comment: That can't be achieved with an unit test. What you looking for is a functionalTest.